# Using Secrets in DotNet 8

Tags: asp.net-web-api, app-secret

When I hardcode my connection string into my project, it works just fine, Also, Azure Key Vault works just fine when in running in release mode. However, when I try to use the Secrets.json, some endpoints still work, but others return this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.InternalOpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

As I mentioned hardcoding the URL works fine, and running in release works fine also,

Here's what I have in my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

#if DEBUG
builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets<Program>();

#else
var vaultUri = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri");
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(vaultUri);
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
#endif
```

and in my db context:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

#if DEBUG
        string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("HomeDatabase");

#else
        string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureDatabase");
        
#endif
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

    }
```

I have tried setting a breakpoint and it seems that for some reason, when in debug, the string sets correctly, but for some reason, after hitting step over a thousand times, it jumps back into the "string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("HomeDatabase");" line at which point the connectionString suddenly becomes null...

Just to add, it seems the simple endpoints work, but if my dbcontxt gets called a second time, that's when the connection string goes null.

if anyone has any ideas, I'd be very grateful.

Thank you. :)

EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

after playing around some more, going to the trouble of creating a new database with a new db context just to handle the tokens. as soon as i added the secrets, again I'm getting the null error...

it seems that the secrets are held up until whichever context is using them has finished.

Comment: The Configuration system can "update" itself in the background, so perhaps why you see the connection changed? have you set the correct things in your usesecrets, the things that DefaultAzureCredential looks for?

Comment: After playing with it some more, it seems like I am calling the context more than once, and that is what's causing the errors... Trying to think of a way around it... since the authorization is a handler that acts on the [Authorize] tag, it seems to encapsulate the http requests and holds up the context... Still weird that it works when the conn strings are hard coded though..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end. I had an authorization handler and a middleware that were conflicting. Fixed it by removing the middleware and having the custom authorization handler handle everything.